# What is the purpose of the base case dp[0] = -1 of this DP array in the palindromic partitions problem?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Recently I came across this problem on https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning-ii/:

Given a string `s`, partition `s` such that every substring of the partition is a palindrome.

Return the minimum cuts needed for a palindrome partitioning of `s`.

```
Example:

Input: "aab"
Output: 1
Explanation: The palindrome partitioning ["aa","b"] could be produced using 1 cut.
```

Here is a C solution I discovered on the internet. I've been trying to understand what the DP array is tracking, and I've figured out that at `dp[j]`, stores the number of palindrome partitions at the `j`th character of the string. So `dp[1]` stores the number of partitions needed for a one letter element, which will always be 0, `dp[2]` that for the first two letters of the strig.

What I don't understand is, why do we initialize `dp[0] = -1`? This seems somewhat unintuitive, and I cannot figure out a reason that this happens.

```c
int _min(int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
int minCut(char* s) {
    int *dp, n, i, k;

    n = strlen(s);

    dp = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(int));     // number of cuts on length
    //assert(dp);

    dp[0] = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        dp[i + 1] = dp[i] + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        dp[i + 1] = _min(dp[i + 1], dp[i] + 1);

        for (k = 1;                 // "aba"
             i - k >= 0 &&
             i + k < n &&
             s[i - k] == s[i + k];
             k ++) {
            dp[i + k + 1] = _min(dp[i + k + 1], dp[i - k] + 1);
        }

        for (k = 1;                 // "aaaa"
             i - k + 1 >= 0 &&
             i + k < n &&
             s[i - k + 1] == s[i + k];
             k ++) {
            dp[i + k + 1] = _min(dp[i + k + 1], dp[i - k + 1] + 1);
        }
    }

    i = dp[n];

    free(dp);

    return i;
}
```

I've done some tracing with this function and still don't seem to be able to find an answer: Here's where I tried minCut("aba"), printing i and dp at the beginning of each iteration of the second wrapping for loop, and also `k` when it appears in the first nested for loop.

```
i = 0
dp = [-1, 0, 1, 2]
i = 1
dp = [-1, 0, 1, 2]
k = 1
i = 2
dp = [-1, 0, 1, 0]
```

When we come to element `'b'`, we find out, by expanding forwards and back that `"aba"` is a palindrome. Then, with this: `dp[i + k + 1] = _min(dp[i + k + 1], dp[i - k] + 1);`, we get that `dp[3] = _min(dp[3], dp[1 - 1] + 1) = _min(2, -1 + 1) = 0`.

It is confusing why the base case is `dp[0] = -1`, and how it factors into `_min(dp[3], dp[0] + 1)`. Basically we are going back to where we didn't have the palindrome detected and taking that value + 1. But why is `minCut("") = -1`?

I've been trying to figure this out for 2.5 hours, but I still cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a guard value. We use such things when we don't want to write additional `if`s, then we append some *guard* elements to the data, e.g. instead of `n*n` matrix we might use `(n+2)*(n+2)` matrix with some convenient values in guards positions, often zeroes.

Observe that with every next palindrome discovered you need to do one more cut. This is achieved by `+ 1` while updating `dp`. But when you discover first palindrome you don't need to do a cut for it. This is the same as with rod cutting, to cut a rod into one piece you don't need to cut it at all.

BTW, if `s` is zero length, the program return `-1` which is wrong.

BTW2, this program takes a lot of time to run if input string looks like `aaa...aaa`. Basically, it is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I was overcomplicating this and thought it was some sort of elaborate base case haha